# What is pythonic way to update custom list of object variables?

Tags: python

Cannot clearly understand right way to create CRUD interface for entity.
For example: 
I've got entity `Event` with variables `date`, `place` and `name`.
I've got basic constructor for this entity with default (nullablle) values.

```
class Event:
    def __init__(self, date=None, name=None, place=None):
        self.date = date
        self.name = name
        self.place = place
```

Trying to figure out pythonic way to create update handler for this entity, which allows me to update custom number of entity fields (*for example: update name and place, without specifying date*).

How I see this:
Use list of custom attributes in update method like `update_event(**kwargs)`, then parse `**kwargs` list and match them with entity using `.hasattr()` or `.getattr()` functions.
Its seems working (and able to find actual diff between entities, which is useful too), but looking pretty harsh.
Basic version with setting all values from kwargs looks like this:

```
def update_event(self, **kwargs):
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        self.__setattr__(key, value)
    return self
```

If we need to check if for diff, we already got:

```
def update_event(self, **kwargs):
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        if self.__getattribute__(key) != value:
            # We got diff
            self.__setattr__(key, value)
        else:
            # We got same value stored already
    return self
```

Maybe im missing something and there are more elegant and simple solutions to this problem, or some design patterns to look for?

Tnx for answers and sorry for dummy questions.

**UPD**: One more point I see: simple `__setattr__` doesn't check that such variable exists. So, if `**kwargs` contains invalid argument name I get Attribute Error.
The obvious fix for that is to create check for `.hasattr()` but as I see it will return False if variable declared but has `None` value.

Comment: Please show your code for: *Its seems working (and able to find actual diff between entities, which is useful too), but looking pretty harsh.*.

Comment: Perhaps you could update your question with an attempt at this `update_event()` method, using `.hasattr()` etc.

Comment: Tnx for feedback, guys. Added `update_event() ` code to the topic.

Comment: How general of an answer are you looking for? Should it work with any class? Or do you want something that will work only with `Event`.

Comment: I want use it to specific entity\model (Event for example), but if it possible to create something more universal - it will be fine :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check that you are only overwriting existing attributes:

```
def update_event(self, **kwargs):
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        if hasattr(self, key):
            setattr(self, key, value)
    return self

def __repr__(self):
    return 'Event: ' + str(self.date)

f=Event()
print(f)
f.update_event(date=1)
print(f)
```

Output:

```
Event: None
Event: 1
```

Comment: Thanks, i ve generally came to same code while writing this post. 
Is far i can see, it doesnt work if variable declared but doesnt has value (setted to `None`).

Comment: Sorry, thats my bad, i was using `.__getattr__` instead `hasattr()`, and its expectedly return None.

Answer (score 2):

View this documentation [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr)
try to use it this way, I may be wrong, but I think it's better.

```
def update_event(self, **kwargs):
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        setattr(self, key, value)
    return self
```